# Sharepoint List Threshold Limit Causing the sharepoint designer workflow to Suspend

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list, list-view-threshold

One of the task lists which was used in designer workflow reached the threshold limit and because of which the workflows are suspending with the below error.

RequestorId: f307e5c6-0c50-b022-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"error":{"code":"-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."}}}

There is a line in the workflow where it fetches the assignedTo field with taskname filter condition and the same exact line is throwing the above error.

Can someone please suggest to me how to overcome this error without increasing the threshold limit because the list can hold upto 30 million items as Microsoft document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why my workflows were getting suspended after the Tasklist reached the threshold limit.
The action inside the workflow which was trying to fetch the item from the task list was querying with an empty filter condition.
Like - `<url>?$select=Id&$filter=Status eq ''` because of which the workflows were getting suspended. When the list items were below 5000 the workflow was running normally but when the items reached above the threshold limit the above action returned an error - `The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.`

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the workflow task list?
[image]
Per my understanding, if the upper limit is exceeded, you could try to create a new workflow task list in SPD.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Elsie Lu_MSFT, Thank you for your reply. Yes, I am referring to the SharePoint Task list. As the list is in the production system I do not want to move data to another task list but use the same task list. I assume the items in the list can be more than 5000 and this issue I am facing is only in the designer workflow while retrieving data from the list.